# ListBox with wrapping and virtualization

Tags: silverlight, listbox, silverlight-4.0, virtualization

I'm trying to configure a ListBox in Silverlight to get both Wrapping and virtualization.

Here is my current solution, with Silverlight toolkit WrapPanel:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel/> 
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <my:MyControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>  
</ListBox>
```

This code get the wrapping correct. However the virtualization is disabled: If I add a log to the constructor of MyControl, I can see that a control is created for item in the collection, even if they are not visible. This is a problem in my case because the object to display and the control are heavy and take too much RAM.

Comment: I have implemented a simple virtualized wrap panel : in my case, all the items always have the same size, so the implementation is simpler.

Comment: Could you share your implementation please?

Comment: I've done it for work, so unfortunately I can't. However you can inherit from VirtualizingStackPanel and use the sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.arrangeoverride(v=vs.95).aspx as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a [VirtualizingWrapPanel for Silverlight](http://blog.hibernatingrhinos.com/12515/implementing-a-virtualizingwrappanel). The source is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/samueldjack/VirtualCollection/blob/master/VirtualCollection/VirtualCollection/VirtualizingWrapPanel.cs).

One thing to note is that, to keep the implementation simple, all the items have to be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a free Virtualizing WrapPanel for Silverlight, however I have found one for WPF.  You may be able to convert it to Silverlight.  Traditionally, creating Virtualized Panels is VERY hard to get right.

[Virtualizing WrapPanel for Silverlight ($900?)](http://www.binarymission.co.uk/Products/WPF_SL/virtualizingwrappanel_wpf_sl.htm)

[Virtualizing WrapPanel for WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VirtualizingWrapPanel.aspx)

Comment: Yes you're right creating a virtualizing panel seems very hard. But actually I'm in a simpler case because all my items have exactly the same size (known before loading the item). Do you know of a virtualizing "WrapPanel" that force all the items to the same size?

Answer (score 0):

The only one (commercially available) at this time that can do this is the virtualizing wrap panel control sold by www.binarymission.co.uk

It also does customised grouping, group header rendering, etc. along with virtualization + wrapping.
It is costly, but worth every penny, and solved my requirement. Mine is an online photo album application, and the control was all is required for the app, rest is all simple UI we have put together, and we can recover the control cost in no time :)
Their support is excellent as well. Replies comes almost within 10 minutes ;) something that you do not generally expect from a 3rd party control vendor, but i guess their price certainly takes care of that :)

Joe I have fixed the link you had in there.
Until somebody has peer-reviewed it it won;t be visible to all, so here is the fixed link:
[Binarymission Virtualizing Wrap Panel for WPF & SL](http://www.binarymission.co.uk/Products/WPF_SL/virtualizingwrappanel_wpf_sl.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your input, this component is worth a test.

Comment: Just one note there. Because the control is obfuscated heavily, if you run your application with the control using any tracing tool - say Intellitrace, you may see an error loading your app (depends on how deep your trace), since the control does not want to be traced into. I turned off Intellitrace during my evaluation, and it was doing its magic absolutely fine. Once i purchased it, I asked for help in being able to trace my app, and to my surprise the company sent to me a tracing friendly assembly (probably with very less obfuscation?) so i could trace the app with the dll. Very nice guys!